# Print lines when Last digit of two files are same

Tags: python

I have a file1

```
AI21T A1,A2,B,Zn |3
AN3DT A1,A2,Z |2
AO22T A1,A2,B,Z |3
BUFF1 I,Z |1
```

and file2 as

```
AO22T A1,A2,B,Z |3
```

I want to compare last digit of file2 with last digit of file1 and if matches then print that match line from file1 in fout file.
The output should be fout

```
AI21T A1,A2,B,Zn |3
AO22T A1,A2,B,Z |3
```

I tried the code

```
f1=open("file1","r")
f2=open("file2","r")
fo=open("fout","w")
  for line1 in f1:
     l1=line1.strip()
     for line2 in f2:
        l2=line2.strip()
        if l1[-1:].isdigit()==l2[-1:].isdigit():
           data=f1.readlines()
   print >> fo,data
```

But I am getting error while comparing and writing in file.

Comment: `print >> fo,data` - why are applying binary right shift (`>>`) at `print` built-in function?

Comment: `isdigit()` returns `True` or `False`. In the line, `if l1[-1].isdigit()==...`, you are basically saying if they are either both digits or both not digits then proceed. Never do you actually check if they are the same digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you first get the data into lists that look something similar to this:

```
f1 =[
    "AI21T A1,A2,B,Zn |3",
    "AN3DT A1,A2,Z |2",
    "AO22T A1,A2,B,Z |3",
    "BUFF1 I,Z |1"
]

f2 = [
    "AO22T A1,A2,B,Z |3"
]
```

This will allow you to easily loop through the file's data without having to worry about line breaks.

Then, you can loop through the data from file1 and loop through the data from file2:

```
for line1 in f1:
    for line2 in f2:
        if line1[-1] == line2[-1]: # compare the last digit of each line
            # write to file, etc.
```

If you're looking for a one-liner, you can use list-comprehension to create a new list of all of the lines in file1 that have a common last digit with the lines in file2:

```
common = [line1 for line1 in f1 for line2 in f2 if line1[-1] == line2[-1]]
```

Output:

```
['AI21T A1,A2,B,Zn |3', 'AO22T A1,A2,B,Z |3']
```

You can then write to a file easily:

```
for line in common:
    fo.write(f"{line}\n")
```

Comment: How can i get my file data into list form f1 and f2?

Comment: I am getting invalid syntax at ```fo.write(f"{line}\n")```

Comment: Yes got the output. Little fix on code split the file 1 and 2 and replace line with ```fo.writelines("line")```. Thanks

Comment: You may have been getting the syntax error due to the python version you are running. `f-strings` were introduced in Python 3.6 which is still pretty recent. I am glad that you solved your issue, enjoy! You can also use `format` like so: `fo.write("{}\n".format(line))`

Answer (score 0):

You've shown not effort to write data, but this should work for your first question.

```
f1=open("file1.txt","r")
f2=open("file2.txt","r")
fo=open("fout.txt","w")


for line1 in f1:
    for line2 in f2:
        if line1.split('|')[1] == line2.split('|')[1]:
            print(line1, line2)
            data = (line1, line2)

fo.writelines(data)
```

Comment: i've edited it, what do you want the variable ```data``` to contain

Comment: The data should have all lines of file1 whose last digit is matching with file2

Comment: I have run the editted code and getting  error```list object has no attribute 'readlines'```

Comment: The edited code worked,  but its giving me only the first match line of file1 not all match lines of file1. and file2 data.